# Unknown device after reinstalling Windows 10 on HP Laptop

Tags: laptop

I have an HP 15-AF123cl laptop that had the hard drive crash.  I bought an SSD and reloaded windows on it and now one of the devices shows up as missing.  How do I figure out what this is?
[image]

Comment: Did you run windows update yet? if you did click "Scan For Hardware Changes" in device manager in the tool bar.

Comment: There isn’t enough information to identify the device based on the information you provided

Comment: go to hp support page > download all drivers for your version of windows.. || That should solves it. ( :

Comment: I have tried downloading the drivers from the HP site and have verified that I have drivers for all of the available devices.

Comment: I have also ran the windows update and scan for hardware changes option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the device, and look at the device ID in the properties, googling this device ID will normally identify the device for you and allow you to download the correct driver.

However, if everything on your laptop works, it's not a huge issue to just ignore it as well.

Comment: I did this and googled the device which let me to this: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Missing-Unknown-device-Driver-ACPI-ASD0001-2-amp-DABA3FF-amp/td-p/5265670.  I was able to update the driver!

Comment: Thanks for accepting - did it install correctly? :)